# Global catalog says that user from DomainA belongs to Domain Users from DomainB

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I am trying to get detailed information about a user's group membership using directory services queries to the global catalog. I don't want to use `GetAuthorizationGroups()` because it's flaky.

There are 2 domains: DomainA and DomainB. The global catalog server is a domain controller for DomainB. Finally, there is a user (UserA) which is part of DomainA.

I find UserA in the global catalog and look at the `tokenGroups` property to get the SIDs of all groups to which UserA belongs.

To my great surprise, I find that `DomainB\Domain Users` is included in the list. **Why is this being included, given that UserA is not part of DomainB?**

Here is the code I'm running:

```
using (DirectoryEntry gc = new DirectoryEntry("GC:"))
{
    string userPrincipalName = "UserA@DomainA.local";

    DirectoryEntry searchRoot = null;
    gc.AuthenticationType = System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

    // There is only 1 child under "GC:".
    foreach (DirectoryEntry de in gc.Children)
    {
        searchRoot = de;
        break;
    }

    using (searchRoot) 
    {
        SearchResult samResult;
        using (var samSearcher = new DirectorySearcher())
        {
            // Find the user.
            samSearcher.SearchRoot = searchRoot;
            samSearcher.Filter = "(userPrincipalName=" + userPrincipalName + ")";
            samSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");

            samResult = samSearcher.FindOne();
        }

        List<byte[]> tokenGroups;
        using (DirectoryEntry theUser = samResult.GetDirectoryEntry())
        {
            theUser.RefreshCache(new string[] { "tokenGroups" });

            tokenGroups = theUser.Properties["tokenGroups"].Cast<byte[]>().ToList();

            IdentityReferenceCollection irc = new IdentityReferenceCollection(tokenGroups.Count);
            foreach (byte[] groupSidBytes in tokenGroups)
            {
                irc.Add(new SecurityIdentifier(groupSidBytes, 0));
            }

            List<string> groupNames = 
                irc.Translate(typeof(NTAccount), true)
                   .Cast<NTAccount>()
                   .Select(a => a.Value.ToString())
                   .ToList();

            return groupNames;
        }
    }
}
```